# Извлечь названия картинок из русскоязычного текста на PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, функции

Есть текст вида:

```
Приблизительно такой primer.jpg. Может быть и так ((drugoi_file.png)) Что-то подобного плана.
```

Задача извлечь из него названия картинок с расширениями на PHP.
То есть на выходе желателен массив [primer.jpg][drugoi_file.png]

Я не умею писать регулярные выражения, пробовал сделать это функциями. Пока не добился успехов. Некоторые тексты получается обработать, некоторые нет. Как бы сделали вы?

**Пока не могу отвечать на свои сообщения, так что добавлю здесь.**
Исходный файл это выборка из базы данных, я просто записал пример в переменную.
Названия файлов пробелов не содержат, об этом забыл написать.
Название может встречаться либо произвольно в тексте, оно будет отделено пробелами или переносами строки. Или внутри двойных скобок с подписью, например ((file_name.jpg Подпись название))/
По идее рег эксп должен подойти нормально.
Пока решил самописной функцией, которая сначала находит .jpg и потом двигается обратно до первого пробела или скобки.

Comment: Уточню:  
все что между двойными скобками обязательно имя файла?  

    ((это имя файла и не важно, что на него совсем не похоже))
Или имя файла это просто латинские буквы, цифры, тире, подчеркивание, а после них расширение?  
То есть желательно уточнить алфавит.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже не очень силен в регулярках, но попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$str = 'Приблизительно такой primer.jpg. Может быть и так ((drugoi_file.png)) Что-то подобного плана.';
preg_match_all('/([a-z_-]+\.[png|jpg|gif]+)+/i',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => primer.jpg
    [1] => drugoi_file.png
)
```

Comment: @deonis, Вы перепутали символьные классы с альтернативой:  

    [png|jpg|gif]

Answer (score 0):

Не понял. Речь идет про исходный текст php или хтмл, который отдает сервер? Короче - что есть исхолный файл?

В любом случае регексп в данной ситуации - костыльное решение. Если необходимо распарсить нечто сложное, нужно брать полноценный парсер и вешать свои обработчики на определенные ситуации. Объясню на пальцах. Регексп,  выдираюший текст вида  "бла-бла-бла.jpg", помимо ссылок на картинки, вытащит и просто аналогичные куски текста, которые не являются ссылками на картинки. Ну, и что делать с тем, что название файла в принцинпе содержит пробелы?

Comment: еще скобки надо раскрывать :) по моему просто задача дурацкая.

Comment: На данном образце текста регулярное выражение- наилучшее решение. Полноценный парсер так же легко может ошибиться.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ждем пока автор нормально сформулирует критерии, по которому нужно обрабатывать исходную информацию.